# How to escape quotes with " in Unload Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, escaping, amazon-redshift

So I am unloading from Redshift using `Unload` operator

```
UNLOAD(
    $$
    select DISTINCT A,B,C

    from Table

    $$)
    TO 's3://{}'
    IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam::'
    DELIMITER ','
    ALLOWOVERWRITE
    ADDQUOTES
    ESCAPE
    parallel off
    HEADER
    gzip;
```

I have an entry like this

```
"xxx","\"><svg/onload=alert('XSS')//","xxxxx"
```

As you can see the `"` is escaped with `\`. However when I do csv validation here:
https://toolkitbay.com/tkb/tool/csv-validator (Using strict mode)
I get this error,

```
Record #0 has error: extraneous or missing " in quoted-field
unable to parse any further
```

It expects the quotes to be escaped with `"`.
How do I make Redshift escape quotes with quotes?

Comment: I played with the validator you linked, but could not find a format that it considers valid for Strict Mode. So, the problem seems to lie with the validator rather than Redshift. Can you figure out what format you would like Redshift to export, so that the validator is satisfied? I could not find any documentation for a "Strict Mode" definition for CSV files.

Comment: Hi yes. validator is happy when the quote is escaped with the quote

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Can you show me some sample input for the validator that satisfies the "Strict Mode"? We can then figure out how to make Redshift output data in that format.

Comment: this is what worked
```"xxx","""><svg/onload=alert('XSS')//","xxxx"```

Comment: It appears that it is using a double-quote (`""`) as a quote. That is not an output format that Amazon Redshift supports.

Comment: so is there any way around I can make it work?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you want to satisfy the "Strict Mode" on that website? What are you doing with the exported data? It is possible that whatever system is using the exported data can use the `\` Escape method that Redshift uses.

Comment: So I am trying to load this to neo4j and it was complaining about the malformed csv. the website is just for validation.Also Am I doing the escaping right?